# Integration of Custom entity with relationship of views

Tags: views, entities

I have created a custom Entity with few properties like uid, title etc. I have made the entity fieldable so that I can add more fields to my entity. Using this, I have added 2 reference fields.

Also have exposed the entity in a view so that I can render the content of the entity using view.

```
function notification_entity_info() {

  $services['notification'] = array(
    'label' => t('Notification'),
    'base table' => 'notifications',
    'entity keys' => array(
      'id' => 'notification_id',
      'label' => 'title',
    ),
    'entity class' => 'NotificationEntity',
    'uri callback' => 'entity_class_uri',
    'controller class' => 'NotificationEntityController',

    'admin ui' => array(
      'path' => 'admin/notification',
      'controller class' => 'NotificationEntityUIController',
      'menu wildcard' => '%notification',
      'file' => 'notification.admin.inc',
    ),
    'module' => 'notification',
    'access callback' => 'notification_access',

    'fieldable' => TRUE,
    'bundles' => array(
      'notification' => array(
        'label' => t('Notification'),
        'admin' => array(
          'path' => 'admin/notification',
          'access arguments' => array('administer notification'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'views controller class' => 'EntityDefaultViewsController',
  );
  return $services;
}
```

If I add a Relationship to use the fields of the Reference field, then the content of the Entity is only visible to Administrators only. Users of other role are not able to see the content of the view.

```
/**
 * Access callback for Notification CRUD operations.
*/
function notification_access($op, $NotificationEntity = NULL, $account = NULL) {
   if ($op == 'view' && user_access('view notification', $account)) {
     return TRUE;
   }
   else if (user_access('administer notification', $account)) {
     return TRUE;
   }
}
```

Can someone guide me with what I am doing wrong? Do I have to do anything special to make it work?

Comment: Are you sure notification_access returns TRUE for other users? Without the code it is hard to tell, but if only user 1 can see the entity it is likely user_access() does not grant access. Check the permissions table and your access callback.

Comment: Hi @Neograph734,

Have added the code of notification_access() function as well. Can you please help me with what am I doing wrong? Notifications are getting created but is not visible to users other than admins on the site.

Comment: does it work if you only have the access function return TRUE? It also might be the 'normal' users do not have access to the referenced entity? You should look into that as well.It could be why the results are hidden.

Comment: I dont think so its because of that. In the views, if I remove the relationships of the entities, the notifications are visible to the user.

Comment: Then it might be in the access permissions of the related entity.